# Elasticsearch order by type

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm searching an index with multiple types by simply using 'http://es:9200/products/_search?q=sony'. This will return a lot of hits with many different types. The hits array contains all the results but not in the order I want it to; i want the 'television' type to always show before the rest. Is it possible at all to order by type?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by [`sorting`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) on the pre-defined field `_type`. The query below sorts results in ascending order of document types.

```
POST <indexname>/_search
{
   "sort": [
      {
         "_type": {
            "order": "asc"
         }
      }
   ],
   "query": {
      <query goes here>
   }
}
```

Comment: This will sort by type name in alphabetical order, but the author wants it to be in the given order, e.g. _television_, _foo_, _bar_

Answer (score 0):

I do it by adding a numeric field `_is_OF_TYPE` to the indexed documents and set it to `1` for those docs that are of the given type. Then just sort on those fields in any order you want.

For example:

```
Document A:
{ 
   _is_television: 1,
   ... some television props here ...
}

Document B:
{ 
   _is_television: 1,
   ... another television props here ...
}

Document C:
{ 
   _is_radio: 1,
   ... some radio props here ...
}

and so on...
```

Then in ElasricSearch query:

```
POST radio,television,foo,bar,baz/_search
{
   "sort": [
      {"_is_television":   {"unmapped_type" : "long"}},  // television goes first
      {"_is_radio":        {"unmapped_type" : "long"}},  // then radio
      {"_is_another_type": {"unmapped_type" : "long"}}   // ... and so on
   ]
}
```

The benefit of this solution is speed. You simply sort on numeric fields. No script sorting required.